# SharePoint Workflow - Parallel Branches not Working as Expected

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Last night I had to add a parallel branch to my workflow (see Step7 in my screenshot). I added this because I needed a way for the administrator to be able to reset the workflow easily and this parallel branch seemed to achieve that.

Problem is, I can't seem to get to the last step (Impersonation Step) and I imagine it's because after completing Step6, it is then trying to achieve Step7 as well before it moves down.

As a result, my items sit at "reviewed" status, and never move to "Complete".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the "Wait for", try using the "if then" in your parallel process. This is because all of the processes in a parallel box do need to complete before the next serial step.

Answer (score 0):

last step of both workflow should be "stop / end workflow". So your Impersonation step will be added after "set status to reviewed" (in step 6) and "set status to complete" (in step 7). After that you have to include another step - End / Stop workflow in both parallel block.

I know it sounds strange but that's how SPD Parallel block process work :)